# Pagination in Struts 1.2.9 in Java EE

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I tried pagination in Struts in Objectweb Lomboz eclipse version 3.3. But I got a "no class found" error.

The errors are
**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org/apache/commons/lang/UnhandledException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:272)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/UnhandledException
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3728)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2130)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1599)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1441)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2213)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2219)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:456)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3320)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:305)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

I don't know what is wrong with the code. I copied it from viralpatel.net. I've got a feeling that this code is only applicable for struts 2. So, if you have any pagination program for struts 1.2.9, please provide this in an answer.

Comment: "please send me the program.My email id is ..." Now, this is bad habit. Did you know, you get automated mail notification when someone answers you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check the root cause of the error. It clearly states:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/UnhandledException
```

Which means that the class `UnhandledException` (from `org.apache.commons.lang` package) is not found (anywhere in your classpath).

Download the latest Apache Commons library from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) and put the jar inside your project's `WEB-INF/lib` directory or declare the path in the classpath.